# Linq error on select after left join .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-7.0

i have a problem that my linq select is returning error **Nullable Object Mus Have A Value** when i assign left join context

below is my code

```
var list = await (from a in _context.wfe_vendor_orders
                              join b in _context.vnd_header on a.vendor_id equals b.Id
                              join c in _context.wfe_vendor_order_items on a.order_number equals c.order_number
                              join d in _context.wfe_products on c.product_id equals d.Id
                              join e in _context.wfe_vendor_order_status on a.order_status equals e.Id
                              join blck in (
                                  from v in _context.vnd_blacklist
                                  where v.is_blacklist == true
                                  group v by v.vendor_tax into g
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      VendorTax = g.Key,
                                      TotalBlacklist = g.Count()
                                  }
                              ) on b.npwp_no equals blck.VendorTax into blacklistedVendors
                              from blck in blacklistedVendors.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where a.partner_id == partnerId && a.order_status != 9 //exclude draft status
                              select new MonitorOrderVm()
                              {
                                  orderNumber = a.order_number,
                                  date = a.CreatedDate == null ? DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") : a.CreatedDate!.Value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("id-ID")),
                                  status_id = a.order_status,
                                  status_name = e.status_name,
                                  product_name = d.product_name,
                                  vendor_name = b.vendor_name,
                                  category_id = a.category_id,
                                  blacklist_status = blck != null ? "black" : "green",
                                  blacklist_total = blck != null ? blck.TotalBlacklist : 0
                              }).ToListAsync();
            return list;
```

but when i assign with direct value it's working

```
blacklist_status = "green",
blacklist_total = 0
```

i've already try using `let blacklistStatus = blck != null ? "black" : "green"` it'work but when i assign to select it's return the same error

please help guys, the return in catch alawys the same about **Nullable Object Mus Have A Value**, any answer will be helpful. thanks guys

Comment: Possibly that `blck.TotalBlacklist` is null? Otherwise, you need to use *elimination* method, by comment, uncomment the code to minimize the scope and see which code is the actual reason that cause the issue.